# All day numbers and week days appear in only a single column

Tags: datepicker, twitter-bootstrap

All the day numbers and week days on twitter bootstrap date picker show up in only one column. Could you help me?

Comment: You're probably missing some CSS.

Comment: I've double checked the link to css file. Are there some version issues?

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/143355/datepicker/datepicker.html

Comment: Looks like you use Bootstrap 2.0 and datepicker for previous version of Bootstrap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens when the css part of the datepicker is missing. Grab the less file from https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/657/files and incorporate it to your system, or take it directly in css from the link you posted